# AngularJS with html5 color input - set value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input with type color defined in my controller scope:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="color" value="#f0f0f0" />
    <input type="color" value={{getColor()}} />
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getColor = function () {
        return "#f0f0f0";
    };
}
```

The problem is the color don't get updated when its set by Angular, although when inspecting I see this:

[image]

See: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/01qL3tck/1/).

How to update html5 input color dynamically?

Comment: I don't know whether the JSFiddle has been updated, but the color was changing for me. Just had a slight delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to bind it to your controller with ng-model instead of value.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.mycolor = "#f0f0f0";

    $scope.$watch('mycolor', function(newVal) {
        console.log('newVal ' + newVal);
    });
}
```

Here is updated and working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5ya562/).

Comment: Getting rid of value did the trick, I eventually defined the default value using `ng-init`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/01qL3tck/13/

Answer (score 0):

You don`t even need a **$watch**, just a **$timeout**.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) { 
    $timeout(() => {
        $scope.mycolor = "#f0f0f0";
    }) 
}
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ukL3suf/